# Appending Dataframe to another dataframe with first row removed

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

```
# Import libs
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

# Form Data for passing to the request body
formdata = {'objid': '14'}

# URL
url = "https://www.sec.kerala.gov.in/public/getalllbcmp/byd"

# Query
for i in range(1, 15):
    formdata["objid"] = str(i)
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=formdata, timeout=1500)
    out = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(out,"html.parser")
    bat = json.loads(soup.text)
    df = pd.DataFrame(bat["ops1"])
    df.to_csv(str(i) + ".csv")
```

Right now this query creates 14 csv files. What I wanted is, the for loop to remove the first row of column headers and append the data to a dataframe I created outside the for loop. so that I can get it as single csv file.

I am using BS and Pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of achieving your goal:

```
# Import libs
import pandas as pd
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm ## if using jupyter: from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
# URL
url = "https://www.sec.kerala.gov.in/public/getalllbcmp/byd"

# Query
for i in tqdm(range(1, 15)):
    formdata = {'objid': i}
    r = requests.post(url, data=formdata)
    df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()["ops1"])
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
final_df.to_csv('some_data_saved.csv')
print(final_df)
```

Data will be saved to a csv file, and also printed in terminal:

```
100%
14/14 [00:14<00:00, 1.05s/it]
value   text
0   8o7LEdvX2e  G14001-Kumbadaje
1   jw2XOQyZ4K  G14002-Bellur
2   0lMB1O4LbV  G14003-Karadka
3   zodLro2Z39  G14004-Muliyar
4   dWxLYn8ZME  G14005-Delampady
... ... ...
1029    Qy6Z09bBKE  G01073-Ottoor
1030    ywoXG8wLxV  M01001-Neyyattinkara
1031    Kk8Xvz7XO9  M01002-Nedumangad
1032    r7eXQYgX8m  M01003-Attingal
1033    b3KXlO2B8g  M01004-Varkala
1034 rows × 2 columns
```

Requests can return responses in JSON format, so you don;t need to import bs4 & json.

For TQDM, please see https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/

For pandas documentation, visit https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Also for Requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a function to get the data and return a DataFrame, then use it within `concat`:

```
def get_data(i):
    formdata["objid"] = str(i)
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=formdata, timeout=1500)
    out = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(out,"html.parser")
    bat = json.loads(soup.text)
    return pd.DataFrame(bat["ops1"])

df = pd.concat([get_data(i) for i in range(1, 15)])
df.to_csv('all_data.csv')
```

*NB. if this gives you unsatisfactory results, please provide a short extract of 2/3 dataframes and the expected merged output.*

Comment: I have added the full code on the original comment as here we have character llimitaions.